# Sql2o keep returning a same set of data although query is different

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sql2o

I am new to using SQL2O with MySQL, but I am having a weird problem, where different queries return same results. Is SQL2O returning me cached results?

My code looks like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT * " +
             "FROM report_A" +
             "ORDER BY :order :sequence "+
             "LIMIT :from, :limit";
    int limit = 5;
    int startIndex = (page-1)*limit;
    String sequence = "DESC";
    try(Connection con = sql2o.open()) {

        if(order.contains("-")){
            order = order.replace("-", "");
            sequence= " ASC";
        }
        Query query= con.createQuery(sql)
                .addParameter("from", startIndex)
                .addParameter("limit", limit)
                .addParameter("order", order) 
                .addParameter("sequence", sequence); 

        List<ReportA> result = query.executeAndFetch(ReportA.class);
        con.close();
```

The 4 parameters always change, but the output remains the same. I have verified the queries in mysql workbench, the data is different, but SQL2O returns me the same set of data. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you use try with resource you don't need to explicitly close the connection. It will be done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is invalid. It wont compile and throw an Sql2oException on  execution.

The problem is, basically, that you can use parameters only for *values*, not for table names, column names or other keywords like "ASC". Changing those would change the *structure* of the query.

It's possible to construct queries with variable structure by good old string concatenation, i.e.

```
String sql = "SELECT * " +
         "FROM report_A" +
         "ORDER BY " + order " " + SEQUENCE +
         "LIMIT :from, :limit";
```

and then

```
query(sql)
    .addParameter("from", from)
    .addParameter("limit", limit)
    .executeAndFetch(...)
```